# On Pie spinner is not showing data as well as social media integration is not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm facing two issues regarding android pie version these are
1) My social media integration is not working :- I have integrated facebook in my code.Code is in kotlin. When I'm clicking on custom facebook button then after successful login with facebook it's not moving on home screen.It show login screen .Same code if i run on another versions then it's working .
2) Spinner Value:- I'm fetching data from server and showing list in spinner .Same code is working on another versions but when I'm running this code on Pie it also not working .

Please suggest me here , what should I do for this.

Hope for best solution and answer !!!

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Raj, are you using an emulator for Pie or actual device? What are the exact system environments you are using?

Comment: First of all thanks for interest .I'm using real device .sir,I'm using Samsung galaxy S8+

Comment: What other devices and facebook accounts have you used?

Comment: I tried on Era 2x 3GB android version 6.0 and its working fine

Comment: Is this the same Facebook account?

Comment: yes , for both same account

Comment: What gradle version of the facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'

Comment: Is here someone who can guide me.